# unable to contact snap store error message when trying to install PyCharm on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm

My Ubuntu 20.04 is connected to the Internet and I used update and upgrade commands on the machine and it's up to date now. But when I type `sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic` to install PyCharm Community version, it returns back this error: *error: unable to contact snap store*.
What to do next, please?

I also searched for the program on Ubuntu Software, but it can't find the app either!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was possible and done very easily, after struggling too much with snap, Ubuntu software and facing failure on each, to download and install PyCharm Community using [Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installation-guide.html#toolbox).

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the proxy settings with these commands:

sudo snap set system proxy.http="http://<proxy_addr>:<proxy_port>"

sudo snap set system proxy.https="http://<proxy_addr>:<proxy_port>"